# DidSelectRowAtIndextPath give me wrong details

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview with custom cells, when I click on one of my cells it shows me the next viewcontroller ( which is the details of the view controller ) as it should be, the details that assigned to this cell ( received from JSON and saved locally as dictionary ) is totally wrong and when click back and re enter this cell gives me right things as my expectations

Any explanation please?

My code

Here how I fetch the data

```
func getMyNotifications() {


Alamofire.request("\(Constant.GetMyNotifications)/-1", method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default , headers: Constant.Header ).responseJSON { response in


    if let Json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {


        if let ActionData = Json["ActionData"] as? [[String:Any]] {

            self.myNotifications = ActionData
            self.generalNotifications = ActionData
            //
            self.myNotificationsTV.reloadData()
            self.counter.text = "\(ActionData.count)"
            self.myNotifications.reverse()


            self.animationView.isHidden = true
            self.animationView.stop()
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
        if self.myBalaghat.count == 0 {

            self.myNotificationsTV.isHidden = true
            self.counter.text = "no notificatins to show"
        } else {
            self.myNotificationsTV.isHidden = false

        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if segmented.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        return returnCell(balaghat: myNotificationsTV, withData: myNotifications, inCell: indexPath.row)
    }  else {

       return returnCell(balaghat: myNotificationsTV, withData: allNotifications, inCell: indexPath.row)
    }

}
```

My didSelectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    generalNotifications.reverse()
    let prepareNum = generalNotifications[indexPath.row]["Id"] as? NSNumber

    currentBalaghId = Int(prepareNum!)
    clickedIndex = indexPath.row
    if let text = generalNotifications[indexPath.row]["NotifDateG"] as? String {
        prepareDateforPassing = text
    }

    if let text = generalNotifications[indexPath.row]["Description"] as? String {
        prepareDesciptionforPassing = text 
    }

    if let text = generalNotifications[indexPath.row]["TypeName"] as? String {
       prepareTypeforPassing = text
   }

   if let text = generalNotifications[indexPath.row]["AddedByName"] as? String {

        prepareProviderNameforPassing = text
   }


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    // to remove highlighting after finish selecting
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Many thanx, added

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: add your code for more clarification

Comment: @Larme Added brother

Comment: @PratikJamariya Added brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are doing reverse on your myNotifications array after tableView's reloadData called. So try reload your tableView once you have reversed your myNotifications array as like below.

```
   if let ActionData = Json["ActionData"] as? [[String:Any]] {

        self.myNotifications = ActionData
        self.generalNotifications = ActionData
        //
        self.counter.text = "\(ActionData.count)"
        self.myNotifications.reverse()
        self.myNotificationsTV.reloadData()


        self.animationView.isHidden = true
        self.animationView.stop()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    }
```

Also have you noticed that you are doing reverse on your array(`generalNotifications.reverse()`) whenever you are selecting a cell, which will reverse your array each time. So First time you will get correct value and next time again array will be reversed and wrong value will be returned. Try using reversed array as like below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let reversedGeneralNotifications = generalNotifications.reversed()
    let prepareNum = reversedGeneralNotifications[indexPath.row]["Id"] as? NSNumber

    currentBalaghId = Int(prepareNum!)
    clickedIndex = indexPath.row
    if let text = reversedGeneralNotifications[indexPath.row]["NotifDateG"] as? String {
        prepareDateforPassing = text
    }

    if let text = reversedGeneralNotifications[indexPath.row]["Description"] as? String {
        prepareDesciptionforPassing = text 
    }

    if let text = reversedGeneralNotifications[indexPath.row]["TypeName"] as? String {
       prepareTypeforPassing = text
   }

   if let text = reversedGeneralNotifications[indexPath.row]["AddedByName"] as? String {

        prepareProviderNameforPassing = text
   }


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    // to remove highlighting after finish selecting
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but not solved, It's happen usually when go down so fast and then click on the cell

Comment: I just noticed that you are doing reverse on generalNotifications array every time cell selected. Please check my updated answer.